# Best Approach for Hide the ribbon from anonymous users/

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon, branding

I need to hide the ribbon from anonymous users, but I want them to see the other part of the website as normal, just without ribbon.

I researched this topic and found a lot of examples like

- `SPSecurityTrimmedControl`
- some javascript methods and CSS tricks

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eric Overfields article [Hide the SharePoint Online Ribbon for Anonymous Users](http://ericoverfield.com/hide-sharepoint-online-ribbon-anonymous-users/) explains the topic very well (*it works the same way for on-premise*):

> The often quoted, yet incorrect, solution for hiding the SharePoint ribbon for anonymous users is to encapsulate the entire suite bar / ribbon with the SPSecurityTrimmedControl with AuthenticationRestrictions set to AuthenticationRestrictions. The problem with this solution is that the out-of-the-box SharePoint JavaScript that is used to determine the height of the s4-workspace requires a div with an id, s4-ribbonrow.
>
> My preferred SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2013 solution for hiding the suite bar / ribbon for anonymous users uses the above theory while also addressing the #s4-ribbonRow requirement. I also find is much cleaner than what is found in the oslo master page.
>
> Simply replace the suite bar / ribbon found in your master page with the following:

```
<div id="ms-designer-ribbon">
   <SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AnonymousUsersOnly" EmitDiv="true">
      <div id="s4-ribbonrow" style="visibility:hidden;display:none"></div>
   </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
   <SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AuthenticatedUsersOnly" EmitDiv="true">
      <div id="suiteBar" class="ms-dialogHidden noindex">
         <!--#suiteBarLeft and #suiteBarRight-->
      </div>
      <div id="s4-ribbonrow">
         <!--ootb ribbon controls-->
      </div>
   </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
</div>
```